# Is George a dishwasher?

Tags: poetry, charles-bukowski

In Charles Bukowski's, *["A Man"](https://allpoetry.com/poem/8509497-A-Man-by-Charles-Bukowski)*, what does George mean by *"I'm a dishwasher"*?

> "I'm a man , baby, understand that?"
>
> "I know you're a man , George."
>
> "Here, look at my muscles!" George sat up and flexed both of his
> arms."
>
> "Beautiful, eh ,baby? Look at that muscle! Feel it! Feel it!"
>
> Constance felt one of the arms, then the other.
>
> "Yes, you have a beautiful body, George."
>
> "I'm a man. I'm a dishwasher but I'm a man, a real man."
>
> "I know it, George." "I'm not the milk shit you left."
>
> "I know it."

Answer (score 20):

It means that George's job at the time was washing dirty dishes at a restaurant, bar, or other place that serves food. (You might be familiar with 'dishwasher' as the name of an appliance, but it can also refer to a person who washes dishes.) This is a job that doesn't require a college education. See:

> "I wish I had a college education."
>
> "You don't need one. You have everything you need, George."
>
> "I'm just a flunky. All the shit jobs."

In terms of the relationship between being a dishwasher and being a man, note the following points:

- Being a dishwasher doesn't pay well compared to jobs that require more education, so it doesn't provide the status of 'breadwinner', a traditional masculine role, as successfully as whatever job the 'college guy' Walter has. For example, George lives in a trailer. This is the reason for the **but** in "I'm a dishwasher but I'm a man, a real man": according to some views of masculinity, a "real man" ought to have a higher-paying (or more prestigious) job that gives him a greater ability to provide financial support.
- On the other hand, being a dishwasher is manual labor. According to certain traditional conceptions of masculinity, manual labor is idealized and viewed as more masculine than working in an office. This is connected to the perception of masculinity as involving bodily strength and physical and emotional toughness. You can see that viewpoint pretty clearly in the conversation between Constance and George ("look at my muscles" and "you have a beautiful body, George" help establish how George fits this traditional image of working-class masculinity).

Comment: Splendid! However, your interpretation portrays an irreconcilable dichotomy between the modern conception (i.e. college guy/higher-paying) and traditional conception (i.e. dishwasher/doesn't pay well) of masculinity (*"blue vs. white collar"*), but wouldn't Constance's abandonment of Walter for George, be Bukowski's arbitration as to which conception of masculinity is appealing? Strangely enough it would seem to reinforce the *"bad boy appeal"* by tainting the *"good boy image"* with words like *"soft"*, *"antiseptic"*, but more potently *"he didn't know how to make a woman happy."*

Comment: @sumeric fair enough, but wouldn't Constance's remark; *"All that money, all that education, he was useless."* assuage the **tension between the different conceptions of masculinity** in favour of *"a"* particular conception embodied by George?

Comment: @sumeric what aspect of the discussion *"implicitly acknowledges the alternative viewpoint that money and education are valuable attributes of a real man.."*? If it is were George says; *""I wish I had a college education.""*, Constance's reply  *"You don't need one. You have everything you need, George."* seems to suggest otherwise. Unless off course a distinction between *"valuable attributes"* and *"appealing attributes"* is maintained, but even then appealing/valuable to whom? I suppose it would depend on whether Constance is supposed to represent the crust or crumb of society.

Comment: About "dishwashing is manual labor, which is associated with traditional conceptions of masculinity" in the answer, I think it's the opposite way. Dishwasher and other activities related to house chores are traditionally seen as feminine works. Hence "I'm a dishwasher but I'm a man" makes a lot of sense. If George had a "masculine" job, he wouldn't use "but".

Comment: @Pere: I would say that, as far as stereotypes go, washing dishes is viewed as "women's work" when done in a household, but not particularly in the context of the food service industry (where dishwashing is not a house chore). Compare cooking: home cooking is stereotyped as women's work, but being a chef is stereotyped as men's work. (Note also that the dishes in George's trailer are unwashed.)